# Change HorizontalScrollView's light color - OverScrollMode

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

At the end of the `HorizontalScrollView`, a light appears to show that the scroll content has ended. Is there a way to change this color? It is appearing in my phone as a yellow one. I have already set the `HorizontalScrollView`'s background color to the one that I desire, but this "end-of-scroll" light isn't the one I want.

EDIT:
I just noticed that this light appears due to the `onOverScrollMode` (since API level 9 - see [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html#setOverScrollMode%28int%29)). Is there a way to set OVER_SCROLL_NEVER and also keep the compatibility with the Eclair versions? Or even better: to set the color of this light (if it appears)?

Comment: Does your HorizontalScrollView contain any sort of ListView?

Comment: No. Just a `LinearLayout`. Its my app's top menu, something like the Android Music Player app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no simple way to set the color for the OverScroll EdgeEffect.

To safely set OVER_SCROLL_NEVER and remain compatible with early SDK revs, you can introspect for the setOverScrollMode method and if found call it.  (tested on 3.1 and 2.2)

```
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // find scroll view         
    HorizontalScrollView hscroll = (HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.hscroll);
    try {
        // look for setOverScrollMode method
        Method setOverScroll = hscroll.getClass().getMethod("setOverScrollMode", new Class[] { Integer.TYPE } );

        if (setOverScroll != null) {
            try {
              // if found call it (OVER_SCROLL_NEVER == 2)
              setOverScroll.invoke(hscroll, 2);
            } catch (InvocationTargetException ite) {       
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ie) {
            }               
        }
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException nsme) {          
    }
```

Comment: A pity that I can't change the overScroll's light color... thanks for the code

Comment: The color is actually a drawable that is set as an EdgeEffect on the HorizontalScrollView.  The edge effect variables are unfortunately private to the class and there is no method provided to override them other than setting OVER_SCROLL_NEVER.  So you get the glow that is set with the systems theme and I have not yet found a nice way to override it.  If I figure something better out I'll post it.

Comment: Thanks, @slund... if you find something, let us know =]

Comment: @slund You can do it with reflection. Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Although this question has already been answered, I wanted to add a couple of more ways that you can go about setting the overScrollMode attribute.

1) Create a "layout-v10" folder and put your alternate xml layout with the overScrollMode attribute set as desired.

2) If #1 would mean copying a ton of files and duplication, you can alternatively create a style for the HorizontalScrollView.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `EdgeEffect` color using reflection. The following will work from API 14+:

```
public static void setEdgeGlowColor(final HorizontalScrollView hsv, final int color) {
    try {
        final Class<?> clazz = HorizontalScrollView.class;
        for (final String name : new String[] {
                "mEdgeGlowLeft", "mEdgeGlowRight"
        }) {
            final Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField(name);
            field.setAccessible(true);
            setEdgeEffectColor((EdgeEffect) field.get(hsv), color);
        }
    } catch (final Exception ignored) {
    }
}

public static void setEdgeEffectColor(final EdgeEffect edgeEffect, final int color) {
    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            edgeEffect.setColor(color);
            return;
        }
        final Field edgeField = EdgeEffect.class.getDeclaredField("mEdge");
        edgeField.setAccessible(true);
        final Field glowField = EdgeEffect.class.getDeclaredField("mGlow");
        glowField.setAccessible(true);
        final Drawable mEdge = (Drawable) edgeField.get(edgeEffect);
        final Drawable mGlow = (Drawable) glowField.get(edgeEffect);
        mEdge.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        mGlow.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        mEdge.setCallback(null); // free up any references
        mGlow.setCallback(null); // free up any references
    } catch (final Exception ignored) {
    }
}
```