# Android setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled not working with Samsung Galaxy S3 GT-I9300

Tags: android, android-layout

So the problem is that I can't disable fading edges of my HorizontalScrollView with the device, is there some hack to do this?

Using `setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(false)` doesn't work, also `setFadingEdgeLength` has no impact.

I tested reading the mViewFlags property and it has no fading edge flags set, still fading edges show. Maybe Samsung has some tweak that you cannot disable fading edges?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay found it:

[Change HorizontalScrollView's light color - OverScrollMode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647131/change-horizontalscrollviews-light-color-overscrollmode)

The key is to invoke setOverScrollMode.

Answer (score 2):

I figure it out. In 2.3.1+ there is a configurable attribute 
"Over scroll mode" and I can set it to "never" in Eclipse and it will 
hide the fading edge when you over scroll the content!